# Mostrar estilo según la fecha del día

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, date

estoy armando esta función para un sitio donde el usuario entra y ve una imagen y un texto según el día de la fecha. El problema es que logré hacerlo mediante .click (cuando el usuario hace click en el día que quiere visualizar lo puede ver) pero necesito que cuando inicie la pagina devuelva el resulta del día de la fecha de manera automática.

Gracias a todos!

```js
var fecha;
$('.date').on('click', function(){

 var elemento = $(this);
 
 fecha = elemento.find('.numb').text();
 fecha = parseInt(fecha);
 // console.log(fecha);

 verificandoFecha(fecha);

});

function verificandoFecha(fecha){
 switch(fecha){
  case 10 :
   $('.box.left img').attr('src', 'img/Happiness10.jpg');
   break;
  case 11 : 
   $('.box.left img').attr('src', 'img/02.jpg');
   break;
  case 12 : 
   $('.box.left img').attr('src', 'img/03.jpg');
   break;
  case 13 : 
   $('.box.left img').attr('src', 'img/04.jpg');
   break;
  case 24 : 
   $('.box.left img').attr('src', 'img/720x645/24.jpg');
   break;
  default:
   alert('Aún no está disponible esta imagen.');
   break;
 }
}

var dateToday;
$('.numb').each(function(){
 dateToday = $(this).text();

 if(dateToday === date){
  console.log(dateToday);
  $(this).parent().parent().addClass('today');
  $('.main .box.left img').attr('src', function(){
   verificandoFecha(fecha);
   // console.log('url image');
  });
 }
});
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box left">
   <span>
                <!-- <img src="img/Happiness10.jpg" alt=""> -->
    <img src="" alt="">
   </span>
            <span class="share">
                <ul>
                    <li><a class="shareFB">Compartí</a></li>
                    <li><a class="download" download>Descargá</a></li>
                </ul>
            </span>
  </div>
  <div class="box right grid">
            <div class="grid-item small oldDay">
    <div class="date">
     <span class="numb">1</span>
    </div>
   </div>
      <div class="grid-item big oldDay">
       <div class="date">
        <span class="numb">2</span>
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class="grid-item medium oldDay">
       <div class="date">
        <span class="numb">3</span>
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class="grid-item big oldDay">
       <div class="date">
        <span class="numb">4</span>
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class="grid-item small oldDay">
       <div class="date">
        <span class="numb">5</span>
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class="grid-item small oldDay">
       <div class="date">
        <span class="numb">6</span>
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class="grid-item big oldDay">
       <div class="date">
        <span class="numb">7</span>
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class="grid-item small oldDay">
       <div class="date">
        <span class="numb">8</span>
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class="grid-item medium oldDay">
       <div class="date">
        <span class="numb">9</span>
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class="grid-item big">
       <div class="date">
        <span class="numb">10</span>
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class="grid-item medium">
       <div class="date">
     <span class="numb">11</span>
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class="grid-item small">
       <div class="date">
        <span class="numb">12</span>
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class="grid-item medium">
       <div class="date">
        <span class="numb">13</span>
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class="grid-item big">
       <div class="date">
        <span class="numb">14</span>
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class="grid-item medium">
       <div class="date">
        <span class="numb">15</span>
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class="grid-item medium">
       <div class="date">
        <span class="numb">16</span>
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class="grid-item small">
       <div class="date">
        <span class="numb">17</span>
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class="grid-item big">
       <div class="date">
        <span class="numb">18</span>
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class="grid-item small">
       <div class="date">
        <span class="numb">19</span>
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class="grid-item small">
       <div class="date">
        <span class="numb">20</span>
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class="grid-item medium">
       <div class="date">
        <span class="numb">21</span>
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class="grid-item medium">
       <div class="date">
        <span class="numb">22</span>
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class="grid-item big active">
       <div class="date">
        <span class="numb">23</span>
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class="grid-item small active">
       <div class="date">
        <span class="numb">24</span>
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class="grid-item medium">
       <div class="date">
        <span class="numb">25</span>
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class="grid-item big">
       <div class="date">
        <span class="numb">26</span>
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class="grid-item small">
       <div class="date">
        <span class="numb">27</span>
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class="grid-item big">
                <div class="date">
                    <span class="numb">28</span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="grid-item medium">
                <div class="date">
                    <span class="numb">29</span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="grid-item small">
       <div class="date">
        <span class="numb">30</span>
       </div>
      </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Hola Mauricio, no está claro para mi lo que intentas... en el `window.onload`  puedes definir que quieres que suceda cuando se cargue la pagina

Comment: Ahí edite el código tal cual lo tengo. Mediante .click logro que se arroje el resultado, pero ademas de eso necesito que cuando se inicia la web por defecto muestre el resultado del día. Necesito ambas cosas. Espero que quede más claro, estoy a disposición. Gracias

Answer (score 3):

Quieres tener la fecha del dia

```
 var fecha = new Date();
```

luego de tenerla visualiza el dia

```
 var dia = fecha.getDay();
```

ejecuta tu consulta

```
verificandoFecha(dia);
```

Comment: te recomiendo usar `getUTCDay()` para que no haga cosas raras ^^